# In iOS7.1 UIButton set image not working?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios7.1

```
[_firstPrincipleButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"i_press.png"]
                                 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

The above code is working fine in iOS7 but in iOS7.1 this is not changing the image of UIButton. I have also tried to do this with setImage but didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: Is this replicable with other buttons and same image, or same button and different image?

Comment: Same button and different images.

Comment: What's its buttonType?

Comment: This is even not working for different buttons and same image. Means say i have 5 UIButton i want to change there image after some user interaction.

Comment: Button type is Custom.

Comment: Are you doing this in viewDidLoad?

Comment: From server i am getting continuous values and then i am calling a method in this way [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(test:) withObject:someobject waitUntilDone:NO]; Based no these values i need to change the UIButton image in test function.

Comment: Is button in table view cell? Have you tried to put images in `Images.xassets`? Will it work if you change title?

Comment: Good point vokilam. I will try this and let you know.

Answer (score 9):

Just in case that others have the same problem and need another hint on how to fix this:

I also had this problem and finally found out that setting a button's (background) image doesn't work on iOS 7.1, if the button is disabled.

Not sure if this fixes your problem, but it was mine. Calling `setNeedsLayout` didn't help in my case, unfortunately. What you can do as a workaround is either to override UIButton or to add a category that contains a method like the following to set an image:

```
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)img forButtonState:(UIControlState)state
{
    BOOL shouldEnable = self.enabled;
    self.enabled = YES;
    [self setImage:img forState:state];
    self.enabled = shouldEnable;
}
```

Filed a bug report for this issue (16497031).

Comment: Actually this works! +1! Just make sure to change the subclassed method to setBackgroundImage, not set Image! goodluck all!

Comment: I wasn't sure if @user2893180 wanted to set the image or the background image of the button, but it should work for both.

Comment: yeah for someone reason when I tried subclassing `setImage:` it just made the button area blue. I may have missed out on a step tho it was almost 5am. either way, background works for me!

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction, but I had set the button to Selected in IB, and nothing I did in code changed the image because I was using UIControlStateNormal

Comment: This seems fixed in iOS 8. Stilla  gotcha for iOS 7 laggards though!

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in iOS 7.1 ,

you can create a category for UIButton and implement a method to set the image  somewhat like this.

```
-(void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forButtonState:(UIControlState)state
{
  CGFloat version = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion].floatValue ;
  if( version  <= 7.1)
  {
      BOOL isFirstTime = YES ;
      for(UIView *aView in self.subviews)
      {
          if([aView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
          {
              [(UIImageView *)aView setImage:image] ;
              isFirstTime = NO ;
              break ;
          }
      }
      if(isFirstTime)
      {
          CGRect frame = self.frame ;
          frame.size = image.size ;
          UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
          [imageView setImage:image];
          [self addSubview:imageView];

      }
      
  }
  else
      
    [self setImage:image forState:state];
    
}
```

This will work.

## enjoy coding :)